# Python String Replace. Cannot escape Quote " without adding two escapes?

Tags: python, escaping

I'm trying to replace `"` quotes in strings with Python. When I use 
`myString.replace('"','\"')` the escape does not work. When I use `myString.replace('"','\\"')` it adds two escapes in it. I'm baffled by it as I just want one escape.

Here's a sample string I want to replace the values in
Exception occurred:

```
myString = """HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'testvalue\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:/hosts?testURL (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(\"bad handshake: Error([(\'SSL routines\', \'tls_process_server_certificate\', \'certificate verify failed\')])\")))'"""
```

As you can see there are two " quotes in the string. I want to add an escape before them. When I try it with `myString.replace('"','\"')` 
(where mystring is the string) nothing happens but when I use `myString.replace('"','\\"')` two escapes appear & this causes issues.

I'm confused by this if I'm honest. Any tips would be appreciated on how this can be set correctly.

Thanks in advance for any help on it.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting the actual string contents mixed up with what the `repr` of the string looks like, and what the string literals you wrote look like. You'll have to understand that difference first if you want to get this right.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why do you need to replace quotes in a ...stack trace? error message?

Comment: When testing your string with a \ and \\ I get the exact results I expect. The first option returns a string without quotes and the 2nd option returns a string with a single backslash where each quote was.

Comment: Thanks all. I think I'm just getting confused with how escape characters & other python items work. When I escape it, it does escape ok but when I add it to a list it then adds a second backslash somehow & it's from the list I was debugging & noting two backslashes. I need to figure out how I can stop lists auto-escaping when I add items to it.

Comment: I need what I add to the list to stay as a true reflection of what I'm adding to it, with no changes.

Comment: Apologies if I'm confusing not just myself but yourselves on this also.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
In [1640]: print(myString.replace('"','\\"'))
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='testvalue', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:/hosts?testURL (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(\"bad handshake: Err
or([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])\")))'
```

Python represents backslashes in strings as `\\` because the backslash is an Escape Character .

If you print it, you will get single backslash.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need an **extra backslash**: myString.replace('"', '\"')

It shows the "\" as escaped but if you print the resulting string, you will see that it's only one backslash.